# Post-hoc test on mixed model - function for groups display

Tags: r, mixed-models, posthoc

I want to run post-hoc tests for a linear mixed model. I’ve initally used `lsmeans∷lsmeans`, which works fine. Problem is: with `lsmeans`, the result is not “sorted” in groups (say: a ab b c etc.), at least not that I know of. So I’ve sorted the groups manually. As I have many treatments in my experimental design, and many post-hoc tests to run, this is somehow painful (and error-prone).

I’ve looked at `agricolae∷HSD.test`, which does give groups for post-hoc tests. Downside is that `HSD.test` does not run with mixed models (neither do `multcomp::cld`, `multcomp::hsd`, nor `multcomp::multcompLetters` for that matter).

**EDIT: ANSWER**

```
# here, the groups are sorted so that the highest mean is "a"
library(lsmeans)
comp_2_by_2<- lsmeans(model, pairwise ~ FactorA:FactorB)
groups_HSD<- cld(comp_2_by_2, alpha=0.05, Letters=c("a","b","c","d"), reverse=TRUE)
```

Comment: Have you tried `cld(lsmeans(...))`?

Comment: In other words. **lsmeans** provides a `cld` method for `ref.grid` and `lsmobj` objects. See its documentation.

Comment: @rvl: thanks for your time (and sorry for my delayed answer, I had the flu). `cld` works nicely, as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @rvl, post as answer ... ?